# Minimal sample program for for RaspiCam CV API not compiling

Tags: raspicam

I try to use the OpenCV Interface of Raspicam (Version 0.1.3).

A minimal example won't compile:

Contents of`main.cpp`

```
#include <raspicam/raspicam_cv.h>
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc,char **argv ) {
    raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;

    return 0;
}
```

Minimal command to compile and link:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I/usr/local/include/ -lraspicam -lraspicam_cv
```

Throws this errors:

```
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::getContrast()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setExposure(raspicam::RASPICAM_EXPOSURE)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::getId[abi:cxx11]() const'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setISO(int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::grab()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::~Private_Impl()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setHeight(unsigned int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::setWidth(unsigned int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setShutterSpeed(unsigned int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setAWB(raspicam::RASPICAM_AWB)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::setDefaults()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::initialize()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::setVerticalFlip(bool)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setAWB_RB(float, float)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::getId[abi:cxx11]() const'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::Private_Impl()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::setHeight(unsigned int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::getISO()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setContrast(int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setBrightness(unsigned int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setSaturation(int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setWidth(unsigned int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::release()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::getSaturation()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::getHeight()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::setEncoding(raspicam::RASPICAM_ENCODING)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::getImageBufferSize() const'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::getBrightness()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::getWidth()'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::retrieve(unsigned char*, raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::setBrightness(unsigned int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::open(bool)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::setContrast(int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::setSaturation(int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::setISO(int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl_Still::takePicture(unsigned char*, unsigned int)'
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: undefined reference to `raspicam::_private::Private_Impl::setFormat(raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the problem? How do I solve it?

Comment: If you have issues with this question state them here instead of just downvoting. That feedback has no information value. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was within the build process of raspicam itself.

`raspicam_cv` does not link against the object files of its source code.
`raspicam` does link against those.

The solution is to change the `CMakeLists.txt` of raspicam and link against the object files, or simply against `raspicam`.

In `raspicam-0.1.3/src/CMakeLists.txt` line 41:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME}_cv ${PROJECT_NAME} ${REQUIRED_LIBRARIES}  ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

The `${PROJECT_NAME}` (which is just `raspicam`) was missing.

After that build and install raspicam again and everything works.